# Convert text file to sequence array format in Spark Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, sequence

### i have sample.txt:

```
1 2 3
1 3 2 1 2
1 2 5
6
```

how to convert this to become sequence array same as

```
(Seq( Array(Array(1), Array(2), Array(3)),
      Array(Array(1), Array(3), Array(2), Array(1), Array(2)),
      Array(Array(1), Array(2), Array(5)),
      Array(Array(6) )
```

i want to try using text file for prefixSpan mllib Spark, [check this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-frequent-pattern-mining.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
val file = new java.io.File("path/to/sample.txt")
Source.fromFile(file).getLines().map(_.split(' ').map(s => Array(s.toInt)))
```

This will actually produce an iterator (of type `Iterator[Array[Array[Int]]]`), but that can be converted to a sequence using `.toSeq` or `.toList` or similar.

Working with Spark (which I am not in a position to check with right now), this should become something like:

```
val data = sc.textFile("...")
data.map(_.split(' ').map(s => Array(s.toInt)))
```

Comment: i have try like this :
val data = sc.textFile("src/data/sample_prefixspan.txt")
val transactions = data.map(s => s.trim.split(' ')).map(Array(_)
its work, but the result same as

(Seq( Array(1,2,3)),
      Array(1,3,2,1,2),
      Array(1,2,5),
      Array(6))

do you have any advice?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you are saying in your comment - it looks like you are on the right track, but I can't tell quite what the remaining problem is.

Comment: I mean, I have to try and have a result like this **Seq( Array(Array(1,2,3))**, not **Seq( Array(Array(1), Array(2), Array(3)),**

Comment: I just need to change a little bit of code and its works thanks

Comment: Ah, that is different from what you show in your question - just change `s => Array(s.toInt)` to `_.toInt`.